# How can I discover the variable name of an object passed to a method

Tags: java, reflection

I want to display the variable name used for the instance of an object passed to a method.  I can take the 'incoming' object and look at it's declared fields and see it's variable names, but I was wondering if there was an easy way of displaying that name.

I thought I could get a stack trace and get the class name of the calling class and then use a classloader and reflect that class's fields and methods looking for the same type but that is just messy and not foolproof.

The variable name I am looking for is not the one assigned in the method's parameter list, but rather the variable name used in the class that is calling my method.

For example

```
public class Ralph{
   String punch = "mouth";
   public void doIt(){
      GetInfo.showIt(punch);
   }
}

public class GetInfo{
   public static void showIt(Object obj){
      System.out.println("variable name = punch");
   }
}
```

Obviously not compilable code but that's what I would like to be able to know in the showIt() method.

Comment: What about if you say `GetInfo.showIt("mouth");`? In this case what will be the name of variable?

Comment: I am not concerned about that situation.  This is for logging purposes to aid in some debugging in code where I know that situation does not happen.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this. The variable names are not present at runtime.

Comment: You can reflect field names at runtime.

Comment: Field names, not variable names.

Answer (score 4):

What is the meaning of a "variable name"? What if your object has no named variable?

i.e., what if someone calls `showIt("punch")`?

What if the object is referred to by two, three or more variables.

i.e., what if you have

```
String foo = "hello"
String bar = foo;
String baz = foo;

showIt(bar); // you're just passing in the same object referred to by 3 variables
```

This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I've ever seen one. You should be focusing on and asking about the overall problem that you're trying to solve, not on your erroneous solution.

Perhaps you want to use a Map instead?

i.e.,

```
Map<String, FooType> fooMap = new HashMap<String, FooType>();
fooMap.put("Jim", new FooType("Jim"));

// later
FooType myJim = fooMap.get("Jim");
```

The key for Java is not to focus on variable names, for in compiled code, they almost don't even exist. Rather focus on ***references*** -- how are you going to get a handle on the object of choice. There are many ways of doing this including Maps if you want to associate an object with a String for instance, or arrays or ArrayLists to associate an object with an int.

Also, I see that you tagged your question [reflection](/questions/tagged/reflection), but note that reflection won't help here. Again what you need to do is to re-think, re-design your program so that you don't need this requirement.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> The problem I am trying to solve is to get the name of the variable. Sorry if "variable name" was vague. Maybe I should have called it field name. If I pass a class into my object I can get it's declared fields and do a field.getName() and see the name that was used in the code to declare that variable. So I am wanting to find the field name that was used for the object being passed to this discovery class. If that is not possible just say so.

Yes, as multiple folks have told you, this is not possible.

> I think I stated my problem pretty plain. This is for debug/logging purposes.

No you haven't. You've stated and restated your problem with your code attempt but have not told us the rationale for wanting to attempt this approach. You're still pursuing the wrong horse and are still presenting us with an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What we need to know are the specifics behind this, the background behind your `"This is for debug/logging purposes"` statement.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is to get the name of the variable.  Sorry if "variable name" was vague.  Maybe I should have called it field name.  If I pass a class into my object I can get it's declared fields and do a field.getName() and see the name that was used in the code to declare that variable.  So I am wanting to find the field name that was used for the object being passed to this discovery class.  If that is not possible just say so.  I think I stated my problem pretty plain.  This is for debug/logging purposes.

Comment: One person has come close to giving me a direct answer by saying 'You can't do this. The variable names are not present at runtime.'  Which is absolutely incorrect.  You can get field names.  But thanks.

Comment: @bittramp: please. I stated that field names are "almost" non-existent. It can be present in debugging information if the compiler is set up to have them present, but if not, then they are in fact non-existent. They certainly are not necessary for the compiler to work, and again usually what is much more important are references to objects, not field names. Again, objects may have ***multiple*** variables referring to them and thus have multiple field names, or they may have none at all, something that you have refused to address. And you're welcome.

Comment: @bittramp: and you're still not telling us the underlying reason for wanting this information. Why? Is it a state or business secret?

Comment: I do not need to address all these "what if" scenarios people keep trying to add in to the discussion.  This is going to be used on, for some small part, on code generated for web services by wsimport.  The response, request structures will be formed such that none of the stuff talked about here will be going on.  Further more in the aid of debugging the soap transactions the field names will be of importance when examining the XML.

Comment: Given an object, for which I can easily see all of it's internal field names, is it possible to see the field name the object was declared with?  That seems like a simple question but telling me to go rethink my design is ridiculously unhelpful.\

Comment: @bittramp: I sincerely hope you do get a better answer, and that if so, we can all learn something from it, but I don't think that it will come. Still I'll keep an eye on this thread. You might want to put a bounty on it in a few days to stimulate more interest in it from other coders.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that some consideration.